# Robrichards XML Signature PHP xmllib

Tags: php, xml, openssl

I am using Robrichards library for xml signature in PHP8.0
I am able to sign the xml but I want to verify the signature value using key. I have also tried the openssl_verify method and the built-in method available in Robrichards library but it says... "Signature is invalid"

Do anyone knows how can I verify my signature value using key in PHP8.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An XML document signed with the RobRichards library has a `<ds:Signature>` child in the root node. To verify the signature:

- Load the XML document with the `DOMDocument::load` method.
- Create a `RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig` object based on the loaded document.
- Locate the signature using the `XMLSecurityDSig::locateSignature` method.
- Validate the signature node using the `XMLSecurityDSig::validateReference` method.
- Create a `RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey` public key object using the `XMLSecurityDSig::locateKey` method.
- Verify the signature using the `XMLSecurityDSig::verify` method and the public key object.

#### Example

```php
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecEnc;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;

// Load a signed XML document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('./test_signed.xml');

$xmlSignature = new XMLSecurityDSig();
if (!$xmlSignature->locateSignature($doc)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not locate signature node');
}

// Validate signature node.
$xmlSignature->canonicalizeSignedInfo();
if (!$xmlSignature->validateReference()) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Reference validation failed');
}

// Create a public key object based on the key type in the XML.
$publicKey = $xmlSignature->locateKey();
// Load the public key.
$publicKey->loadKey('./rsa_pub.pem', true);

switch ($xmlSignature->verify($publicKey)) {
    case 1:
        echo "Signature is good\n";
        break;

    case 0:
        echo "Signature verification failed\n";

    default:
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'Unexpected error occurred during signature verification',
        );
}
```

For this example, I created a pair of keys using the following commands:

```bash
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rsa.pem
openssl rsa -pubout -in rsa.pem -out rsa_pub.pem
```

Refer to [the library's test cases](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/blob/master/tests/xmlsec-verify.phpt) for more samples.